# How to plot all scalar multiples of a set of points

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

How can I graph the set of all scalar multiples of the points on the surface $(x,x^3,1)$, that is, $\{(t(x, x^3, 1)\mid t,x\in \mathbb R\}$ in mathematica? I tried

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t*x, t*x^3, t}, {t, -10, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

but it gave me an incomprehensible thin, long strip of something.

Comment: Scale the units of the x range. (E.g., look at the result with `{x,-1,1}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Manipulate` and set `BoxRatios -> 1`.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[t {x, x^3, 1}, {t, -a, a}, {x, -b, b}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> All], {{a, 1}, -1000, 1000}, {{b, 1}, -1000, 1000}]
```